# When I click on the ? people in Tiny Death Star it changes to a number

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star, android

When I click on the ? people in Tiny Death Star it changes to a number. But on my wife's game she can take the ? people to any floor.  Is this a glitch?  Can I fix it?

Comment: Are you running the most recent version of the app? I used to have this issue on my device but it went away after an update.

Comment: Have you exited the program and restarted it?

Comment: Just downloaded it yesterday so I hope it's the most recent version.  And I have exited the game and restarted the device.  I will double check for updates, or wait for the next one and maybe that will solve it.

Comment: You may have a corrupt install. Might have to reinstall.

Comment: Where did you download it from?  Perhaps they don't have the latest edition?

Answer (score 4):

If you're running the older version, you will be forced to deliver a ? bitizen to a specified floor.

If you're running the latest, you can deliver the ? Bitizen to any floor you'd like.

Comment: I'm not an Android guy, on iOS it would be nearly impossible to have downloaded the old version.  Is it it possible in Android (say, on the Google Play store?)

Answer (score 2):

Did you download it from the Amazon App Store?  Amazon has an out-of-date version (as they do with MANY apps) that pre-dates the change in behavior for ? bitizens.

Unless you have a Kindle, you can download it from the Google Play store instead.  They are both free and Google does a much better job of staying up-to-date.